# Determining the lowest child-node (descendant with greatest index) in an array-based binary-tree in O(1)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, data-structures, binary-tree

Some binary-tree structures (such as heaps) can be implemented using an array by setting indices left-to-right, top-to-bottom

```
           0
      /        \
     1          2
   /   \      /   \
  3     4    5     6
 / \   / \  / \   / \
7   8 9 10 11 12 13 14
       ... etc.
```

The children and parent of a node at index `x` can be found easily in O(1):

```
child-left(x) = 2x+1
child-right(x) = 2x+2
parent(x) = (x-1)/2
```

But **is there a way to find the lowest descendant of x in O(1)** *(ie. the descendant with highest index)*? For instance, in the tree above, the lowest descendant of `x=0` would be 14, while for `x=1` it would be `10`.  Note that for `x=1`, if there were only 10 elements in the tree, it should return `9` instead.

I can assume there will never be more than 2<sup>32</sup> elements in my array, so 2<sup>n</sup> can be implemented in O(1) using bit-shifts.  Possibly `log_2` as well (???)

Comment: As a silly cop-out answer, if you have at most 2^32 elements in the array, you could always just precompute everything and look up the answer in a lookup table in O(1). :-)

Comment: Is the binary tree necessarily a perfect binary tree (that is, no missing nodes), or might there be some nodes missing off the bottom level?

Comment: @templatetypedef: No, it is not necessarily perfect

Comment: Why for `N=10` the lowest descendant of `1` is `9`?? Why not `7`? What meaning exactly do you put in the term "lowest" in this case?

Comment: @AndreyT he describes it as "Descendant with the highest index" in latest edit

Comment: is it a full binary tree? do we know the height of the tree in advance?

Comment: @xvatar: If by *full* you mean *"as balanced as possible, putting all new nodes on the left"*, then yes.  This is usually the case with binary-trees implemented as arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.  The depth of node x is

```
depth(x) = log2(x+1)
```

Similarly, the i-th left-child and i-th right-child of node `x` can easily be found:

```
ithLeftChild(x, i) = 2i(x+1) - 1
ithRightChild(x, i) = 2i(x+2) - 2
```

The index of the left-most child at depth `d` is `ithLeftChild(x, d - depth(x))`, and similarly for the right-child.

Let's call the index of the last element `n`.  So, now we can find the depth of `n`, and we can also find the indicies of `leftmostChild` and `rightmostChild` at that depth *(which could be larger than the last element, meaning they don't actually exist)*.

Now we just have three cases:

- `n < leftmostChild`.  Then our subtree has no elements at that depth, so the highest index must be `parent(rightmostChild)`.
- `leftmostChild <= n <= rightmostChild`.  Then the highest index is necessarily `n`.
- `rightmostChild < n`.  Then `rightmostChild` must be our highest index.

---

2<sup>i</sup> can be implemented in O(1) for reasonable `i` using bit-shifts; `log2(x)` can be implemented in O(1) [using a 256-byte lookup table](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogLookup).  So the overall algorithm is **O(1)**.

Comment: Was about to type this exact solution out and got distracted with work, +1 for figuring it out though.